# Flutter web - setting height to 100% and not 100vh

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In HTML creating a page that is divided into 2 columns that span **100% of the screen height** is easy

```
<div id="row">

<div id="column1" style="width:75%; height:100%"></div>
<div id="column2" style="width:25%; height:100%"></div>

</div>
```

Using Flutter this seems more complicated than it should be, i tried to achieve the above in a couple of ways: (The page's outline is `CustomScrollView -> SliverToBoxAdapter -> Row -> Columns`)

- Using `MediaQuery` to set the columns' height as `deviceSize.height`. This failed because as the left column got bigger than the right column, the right column did not expand in size to match.
- Using `Expanded` or `Flexible` (tight or loose) to try and expand the height. This did not work.

My question is how do i achieve **100%** height and not **100vh** height in Flutter web?

Edit:

This illustrates the problem, the right column is not expanding in size to match the left column.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverFillRemaining(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.purple,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("test"),
                      SizedBox(height: 300),
                      Text("test"),
                      SizedBox(height: 300),
                      Text("test"),
                      SizedBox(height: 300),
                      Text("test"),
                      SizedBox(height: 300),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[Text("test")],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Ok.. now the question is clear. So you want the yellow Text widget to expand and stretch its height to match height of the list on the left side as and when it grows. This could be slightly challenging as the container holding this widget doesn't share the same constraints as its sibling. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yep sorry for being unclear! Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want. But based on your statement I think you are looking for two column layout as in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_two_columns) and as shown below in the image.

[image]

Following is the code for the same. You can adjust the flex value in the Expanded widget to acquire the required screen width ratio. but if you want to adjust the width each columns like using a drag handle or so, then this alone wont suffice.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FullHeightDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 4,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Column-1',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.teal,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Column-2',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

**Specifying the height using MediaQuery inside a Scrollable widget could help**

Following code places the columns inside a `SingleChildScrollableView` widget and specifies the height of the container based on `MediaQuery` to achieve the same. Will this help.? The `LayoutBuilder` is only there to show that the using the height from its constraints could also lead to error since in this case its height is also `infinite`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FullHeightDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
          return Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: size.height,
                  // height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Column 1',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: size.height,
                  // height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Column 2',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer works if no scrolling is required, but if you add any type of scroll widget it breaks, i tried `SingleChildScrollView`, `CustomScrollView`, `ListView`. Check them out!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. But `SingleChildScrollView`, `CustomScrollView`, `ListView` all these scroll view will try to shrink its children. Inherently these widgets come with height constraint which is `infinity` to accommodate growing number of children and when you put a child which has no height constraints then this becomes a conflict meaning child cannot grow as tall as the list view can and the list view cannot shrink a child without 
 a specificheight. Hence you should always define the height of the children in a `ScrollView` type widget.

Comment: Im trying to achieve the same layout you showed but in a `ScrollView`. If i want to create a website right now in flutter and one of the requirements is that the layout is a multi column layout is it unachievable? Hence my question about the **100% height **

Comment: Im gonna edit my question with a sample code to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: The edited answer still does not solve the issue. I think the only way to understand the issue is to try and create a website with a two column layout, where the right column has more widgets (exceed the viewport height aka add scrolling to the whole page) than the left. If you want copy paste the sample I provided into a `scaffold`.